# Is the following equation True or False given Events A, B, and C?

Tags: probability

I am stuck on this homework question I have and really don't have a clue on how to prove that the following equation is true or false. All help is greatly appreciated! Thanks guys

[image]

Comment: Try a Venn diagram.

Comment: They're not equal, correct? I got Only A coloured in for the left side of the equation and at the end of the right side I get A + the intersection of B and C coloured in.

Comment: No, they are equal.  On the RHS you get $B\cap C$ subtracted twice and then added back once, so overall it is subtracted once, which is the same as the LHS.

Answer (score 1):

Of course looking at Venn diagrams is a great way to start, but
I suppose "justify" requires something beyond "I drew these great diagrams
and...")

Here's part of it:
$P(B \cup C) = P(B) + P(C) - P(B \cap C)$ (general addition rule)
Also, $(B \cup C)^c = B^c \cap C^c$ (one of DeMorgan's laws).
Maybe you can put it together from there.

Comment: IMHO the prejudice against Venn diagrams as proofs is exactly that - a prejudice.  As far as I am concerned, Venn diagrams, **if accompanied by explanations** (as any proof should be) can make up a simple, rigorous and thoroughly convincing proof.